# Unable to get data from csv file into html using <object>

Tags: html, csv, object-tag

I have tried the following code to get the data from csv file to html page,but I am not getting the values.here is my code.

In table.html file,

```
  <html>
<head><title>Reading values into a table</title></head>
<BODY>

<DIV CLASS="body">

<OBJECT id="elements" CLASSID="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
  <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="data.csv">
  <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="True">
</OBJECT>

<TABLE datasrc="#elements">
<THEAD><TR STYLE="font-weight:bold"><TD>Number</TD><TD>English</TD><TD>French</TD><TD>German</TD></TR></THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR><TD><DIV datafld="Number"></DIV></TD><TD><DIV datafld="English"></DIV></TD><TD><DIV datafld="French"></DIV></TD><TD><DIV datafld="German"></DIV></TD></TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>


</DIV>
</BODY>

</html>
```

In data.csv file,

```
number:Int,english,french,german
1,one,un,eins
2,two,deux,zwei
3,three,trois,drei
4,four,quattre,four
5,five,cinque,fuenf
6,six,six,sechs
7,seven,sept,sieben
8,eight,huit,acht
9,nine,neuf,neun
10,ten,dix,zehn
```

It is not working for .txt file also.

Answer (score -1):

Look on this you may get idea.

[using javascript and the HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)